# Python: Popen vs Batch

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to call a Fortran executable from Python, which in turn calls one or more other Fortran executables and a couple of perl scripts when it finishes.  The program is proprietary and I have no access to the source code.

I can run this program from a batch file by simply setting a few environment variables and then calling the executable.  For example:

```
set OPTION1=option1
set OPTION2=option2
set OPTIONPATH=C:\...
C:\PROGRA~2\...\program.exe
```

I can do a similar thing with Python:

```
new_env = os.environ.copy()
new_env['OPTION1'] = 'option1'
new_env['OPTION2'] = 'option2'
new_env['OPTIONPATH'] = r'C:\...'
proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\PROGRA~2\...\program.exe'],
                        env=new_env,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
return_stdout = proc.communicate()
print(return_stdout[0].decode())
```

I can always run the batch file without any issues, however when I run this Python code I occasionally (~10% of the time) get an error along the lines of:

```
forrt1: severe (157): Program Exception - access violation
```

This appears to most likely be some sort of memory issue with Fortran.  But I can't figure out why this would be an issue only when called via Python but is never an issue from the batch file.  If it matters, I'm using Python 3.6 and on Windows 10.  I just switched to Windows 10 last week and I don't recall having this issue on Windows 7.

Could it be something to do with the stdin/stdout pipes or the communicate method?  I did try just using proc.wait() instead of communicate, but it didn't work either.  I'd prefer to caption the stdout in my Python script, but I can live without it if it avoid this memory issue.

**EDIT**

I've also tried the following:

- Using `shell=True`
- Using `executable="C:\PROGRA~2\...\program.exe"` and then setting `args=[]`
- Setting `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to various combinations of PIPE, DEVNULL, and None
- Setting `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`
- Setting `bufsize` to -1, 0, 1, and 4096
- Various combinations of the above
- Running the batch executable with `C:\PROGRA~2\...\program.exe < NUL > output.txt 2>&1` to try to simulate what I do with Python inputs and outputs

In all cases, the batch still works every time and Python with Popen randomly fails.  I do not have access to the Fortran code so re-compiling it is not an option.  I suspect that it is poorly written or buggy, but it seems like I should be able to get the same result with Python as the batch file.  Since I don't recall having this issue with Windows 7, it may be an issue with Windows 10, but it still seems like I should be able to match the batch file output.  When Python runs it without getting a Fortran error, then it does give the correct output.  The Fortran code is 32 bit, if that matters.

Is it possible to make Popen not give EOF to stdin immediately (I tried `DEVNULL` and `None` for stdin)?.

**EDIT 2**

Ok, this isn't likely an issue with Python and Popen.  I've tracked down the issue to one of the the later Fortran programs called by the
executed program.  I can create a batch file that calls only that second program and causes the same access violation that I get from Python.  Still a mystery to me why it never fails when calling the first program from a batch file, but I'm going to look into different solutions at this point.  I'll probably just create a batch file and execute it since that seems to work consistently.

Comment: Might indeed be something with popen. please see its documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) I saw there: `bufsize, if given, has the same meaning as the corresponding argument to the built-in open() function: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size. A negative bufsize means to use the system default, which usually means fully buffered. The default value for bufsize is 0 (unbuffered).
`

Comment: If you just changed to Windows 10 last week, could you possibly simply be running into a bug in the Fortran code that didn't manifest on Windows 7 but does on Windows 10? Can you check the Windows Event Viewer and get any information about the crash in the Fortran program? Could you try recompiling the Fortran program on Windows 10, and/or possibly with a newer Fortran compiler, to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Also: can you try changing the batch file to redirect stdin and stdout for the Fortran program? Some programs that were designed for interactive use (or just programmed buggily) will misbehave if stdin gives EOF immediately (which it will in your case, because you don't pass any stdin data into `communicate()`).

Comment: See my edit, I've tried to various other options without success.

Comment: Why does it matter that it is written in Fortran and not, say, C++? Is the tag needed?

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in Fortran code and it's only visible with memory arrangement when the program is ran by Python process? I don't know Fortran, but there should exist tools to catch this type of problems (debugger AFAIR from my C times).

Comment: The better simulation would be to *pipe* the output to a program (that at least reads it).

Comment: @VladimirF only because it is written in Fortran.  I wasn't sure if perhaps there is something unique that should be done with Popen and Fortran code.  Not likely though, I'll remove the tag.